# UWP # not showing ListView.ItemTemplate since I changed from List to ObservableCollection and async

Tags: c#, xaml, asynchronous, uwp, observablecollection

I had a working solution with a manually created list.
But since I want to read from a file and because of that I had to change to  async and because the amount of data will change in the future to ObservableCollection the XAML doesn't show the 9 rows anymore.

Debugging I see that **{x:Bind Accounts}** still contains the 9 rows and the two values. But **AccountName** and **SumAccountName** data are not are not listed. Only header and footer.
I spent now hours by hours comparing both solutions, but no clue why this one doesn't show the data.

Overview.xaml:

```
x:Class="Finance_Manager.Overview"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Finance_Manager"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data="using:Finance_Manager.Models"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<StackPanel>
        <Grid Margin="20,20,20,20" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Accounts}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Konto" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Total" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Account">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind AccountName}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind SumAccountName}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.Footer>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Gesamtvermögen" />
                    <!-- <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" x:Name="SumTextBlock" TextAlignment="Right"/> -->
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" Text="CHF 326'979.74" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Footer>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Margin="20,80,0,0" x:Name="TextBlockClicked" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Accounts.cs:

```
namespace Finance_Manager.Models
{
    public class Account
    {
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public double SumAccountName { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountOverview
    {
        public static async Task<ObservableCollection<Account>> GetAccounts()
        {
            var accounts = new ObservableCollection<Account>();

            //
            // Load file
            var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var GetOverviewFile = await folder.GetFileAsync("overview.json");
            string jsonString = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(GetOverviewFile);
            //

            JsonArray root = JsonValue.Parse(jsonString).GetArray();
            for (uint i = 0; i < root.Count; i++)
            {
                string account1 = root.GetObjectAt(i).GetNamedString("account");
                double sumaccount1 = root.GetObjectAt(i).GetNamedNumber("sumaccount");
                accounts.Add(new Account { AccountName = account1, SumAccountName = sumaccount1 });
            };

            //accounts.Add(new Account { AccountName = "Bank1", SumAccountName = 100.00 });
            //accounts.Add(new Account { AccountName = "Bank2", SumAccountName = 100.00 });
            //accounts.Add(new Account { AccountName = "Bank3", SumAccountName = 100.00 });
            //accounts.Add(new Account { AccountName = "Bank4", SumAccountName = 100.00 });
            //accounts.Add(new Account { AccountName = "Bank5", SumAccountName = 100.00 });
            //accounts.Add(new Account { AccountName = "Bank6", SumAccountName = 100.00 });
            //accounts.Add(new Account { AccountName = "Bank7", SumAccountName = 100.00 });
            //accounts.Add(new Account { AccountName = "Bank8", SumAccountName = 100.00 });
            //accounts.Add(new Account { AccountName = "Bank9", SumAccountName = 100.00 });

            return accounts;
        }
    }
}
```

Overview.xaml.cs:

```
namespace Finance_Manager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class Overview : Page
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Account> Accounts;

        public Overview()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public async void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Accounts = await AccountOverview.GetAccounts();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Change your `Accounts` field to property

2) If you are using binding you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call OnPropertyChanged() every time you change `Accounts` property. That will update View.

3) By default `x:Bind` using `mode=OneTime`, you should change it to `Mode=OneWay`.

If you want the fastest and simple solution, remove bindings and just do `ListView.ItemSource = MyClass.GetAccounts()`. It is not good for MVVM pattern, but I see that you are using code behind.

Comment: To change field to property is pretty easy - 
`public ObservableCollection<Account> Accounts {get; set;}`

Answer (score 1):

First of all bindings work only with properties not fields (your ObservableCollection Accounts is just field).

And another problem may be that the `Accounts` property will be `null` when XAML is loading, so you may need to add `Accounts = new ObservableCollection<Accounts>();` before `this.InitializeComponents();` and also not to return whole new instance of ObservableCollection from `AccountOverview.GetAccounts();` method but just filling the already existing object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I'm struggling a bit now. I used the example from Channel9 "Windows 10 development for absolute beginners".

How I can change Accounts from a field to a property? Did not find an example which looks different to mine.

Comment: In your case, just change `public ObservableCollection<Account> Accounts;` to `public ObservableCollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

I did all explained, but it was still not working.

I added `Name="AccountList"` to the ListView in the Overview.xaml. And `AccountList.ItemSource = Accounts;` to the Overview.xaml.cs. Now it works.